# Logstash since_write_interval

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Logstash uses the `sincedb` file to store the position it is at in processing a file. In the event of logstash shutting shown before processing is completed, it can use `sincedb` to continue from where it left off.

Running on Windows, the behaviour observed is that the `sincedb` file is only written when logstash closes. This means that if the machine logstash is running on is terminated and logstash's own shutdown routines are not called, no `sincedb` file will be written.

Setting the `sincedb_write_interval` to different values does not appear to make any difference. Even with this set, `sincedb` is only written when logstash terminates or is shutdown.

Below is the basic structure of our logstash configuration.
Are we using `sincedb_write_interval` in the wrong way?

Thanks

```
{
   file {
      path => "..."
      sincedb_write_interval => 10
   } 
}

output {
   elasticsearch {
     host => "..."
     index => "..."
     protocol => "http"
     cluster => "..."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly.

However, the default is 15 seconds so you should not be having the issue.  Could run with some test input then wait a minute and post your sincedb?

Answer (score 0):

sincedb_write_interval matters when Logstash tries to decide whether to pick up from last time's read.

If you do "sincedb_write_interval => NULL", Logstash will re-parse the whole file even though it has parsed it before.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a very old logstash, 1.4.2. But having the same issue. The only value that works is "1". The default 15 doesn't work and no other value apart from "1" also don't work. 
    sincedb_write_interval => 1
Setting it to "1", updates the sincedb immediately.